# Are Electrons Electromagnetic Waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, electric-fields

I encountered a thought provoking article suggesting that [electrons are electromagnetic waves.](http://vixra.org/abs/1106.0006) Is this possible? I may not agree with their entire model, but surely there is the possibility that an electromagnetic wave might impersonate a some aspects of a point charge through aligning its electric component with the electric field.

Comment: This kind of nonsense is basically the reason that arXiv started putting up barriers to entry, which is not to say that there is nothing good on vixra, but you have to be even more wary.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be closed? It isn't mainstream. At all!.

Comment: @dimension10 There is a [difference between being wrong and being non-mainstream](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/a-non-mainstream-flag). This question is asking for clarification regarding an interpretation of mainstream physics and the consensus here is that it is wrong.

Comment: @JoeHobbit alternative explanations to things that are well understood are not only wrong but non mainstream too, since mainstream physicists know what electromagnetic waves and electrons know quite a long time ago.

Comment: @JoeHobbit, for those with some familiarity of the subject of QED, the idea that electrons could actually be EM waves is as odd as the idea that carbohydrates could actually be hydrocarbons, something I believe Velikovsky proposed.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Every theory has its presuppositions, which in the case of QED include the treatment of electrons as point charges. Every answer so far has said essentially that in various ways. The intended purpose of this question was to ask for conclusive experimental evidence for that presupposition. I realize that was not clear and I'm not sure whether to change this question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 9):

Seriously?

- Electromagnetic waves are neutral; electrons are charged.
- Electromagnetic waves have spin one; electrons have spin one half.
- Electromagnetic waves have lepton number zero; electrons have lepton number one.
- Electromagnetic waves have invariant mass zero; electrons have non-zero invariant mass.

All of these things are observables.

Comment: Light waves are of course neutral, but that does not preclude the possibility of a charge bearing variation of an EM wave (especially at a much lower velocity). Some variation would in this case need to have spin 1/2, lepton number 1, and mass.

Comment: @JoeHobbit how could an EM wave have a mass?

Comment: @user6972 See: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71300/is-electromagnetic-mass-possible

Comment: Frnakly, @JoeHobbit you're going to have to show me a solution before I'll buy that.

Answer (score 4):

No, electrons are not electromagnetic waves. The paper is kook material. Electrons are charged. You can't make a charged particle out of electromagnetic waves, which are neutral.

Comment: How does [electron positron annihilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron%E2%80%93positron_annihilation) work then? The premise of the paper is based on electrons and positrons annihilating to form $\gamma$ rays.

Comment: @Joe the pair (taken together) has quantum numbers that are compatible with two or three photons (depending on the orbital angular momentum state). The paper is not even wrong.